# How do you see Error Page Previews

Tags: magento-1.9, error

As the question implies:

I've created a new `errors theme` in `/error/custom/` and edited the `layout.xml` to show the new error pages but I don't know how to test them??

Does anyone know how to force an error or preview the error pages?

By this I mean its easy to force a 404 error just visit www.yourdomain.com/ajdkts.html and it will produce a 404 error.

But how would I force a 500 error or a 503 error? So that I can see that I can preview my changes.

Comment: Updated question as I don't think anyone understood what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the `errors` directory are a few files.  One is `503.php` and the other is `404.php`.  Just point your browser there and it will render those pages:

http:// magento.localdev/errors/503.php

http:// magento.localdev/errors/404.php

To see what a production error would show use `report.php`:

http:// magento.localdev/errors/report.php

Answer (score 1):

To enable error reporting

In your **index.php** add this at top

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

also In Errors folder rename `local.xml.sample to local.xml`

You can also check `var/log` folder

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about 404 and 503 custom pages then here is the link please follow ...
http://inchoo.net/magento/enhance-magento-404-page/

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link:
you get exactly what you want

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-display-error-messages.html#gref